# How to keep object rotating in direction of touch movement?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, rotation, touch

I am looking for following implementation in unity based touch game:

1. I need object to rotate with the touch so it can be viewed from all sides(As long as touch is moving)
2. The object should keep on rotating in direction of previous touch
   movement (when touch ends)
   I tried implementing below code. But rotation is quiet quirky. It sometime rotates too fast sometimes in opposite direction of the swipe etc.
   Here is what i have tried:

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    public class Functionalities : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject m_objecttorotate;
        Vector3 localAngle;
        [SerializeField]
        float rotateSpeed = 0.09f;
        Touch touchZero;
        Vector3 rotateAxis;
        float newMouseYpos = 0;
        float prevMouseYpos = 0;
        bool isIncreasing;
        bool isDecreasing;
        bool rotateManually;
        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);

                //Rotate the model based on offset
                localAngle = m_objecttorotate.transform.localEulerAngles;
                localAngle.y -= rotateSpeed * touchZero.deltaPosition.x;
                m_objecttorotate.transform.localEulerAngles = localAngle;
                if (touchZero.deltaPosition != Vector2.zero)
                {
                    rotateAxis = touchZero.deltaPosition;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                localAngle.y += rotateSpeed * rotateAxis.y;
                m_objecttorotate.transform.localEulerAngles = localAngle;
            }
            CheckIfTouchIsMovingUpOrDown();
            if (isIncreasing)
            {
                Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(m_objecttorotate.transform.position.x, -0.25f, m_objecttorotate.transform.position.z);
                m_objecttorotate.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(m_objecttorotate.transform.position, newPos, 1 * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else if (isDecreasing)
            {
                Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(m_objecttorotate.transform.position.x, 0.25f, m_objecttorotate.transform.position.z);
                m_objecttorotate.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(m_objecttorotate.transform.position, newPos, 1 * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else
            {
                Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(m_objecttorotate.transform.position.x, 0f, m_objecttorotate.transform.position.z);
                m_objecttorotate.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(m_objecttorotate.transform.position, newPos, 1 * Time.deltaTime);

            }
        }

        void CheckIfTouchIsMovingUpOrDown()
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {

                if (prevMouseYpos != newMouseYpos)
                {
                    if (prevMouseYpos < newMouseYpos + 1f)
                    {
                        isIncreasing = true;
                        isDecreasing = false;
                        Debug.Log("Increasing");
                        prevMouseYpos = newMouseYpos;
                    }
                    else if (prevMouseYpos > newMouseYpos - 1f)
                    {
                        isDecreasing = true;
                        isIncreasing = false;
                        Debug.Log("Decreasing");
                        prevMouseYpos = newMouseYpos;
                    }
                }
                newMouseYpos = Input.mousePosition.y;
            }

            else
            {
                //isDecreasing = false;
                // isIncreasing = false;
                prevMouseYpos = newMouseYpos;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're rotating the local angle, which due to the object changing its angle is bound to lead to problems. E.g. [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3pjBQObC90) suggests using `transform.RotateAround(Vector3.up, -rotX); transform.RotateAround(Vector3.right, -rotY);` instead. By the way, something went wrong with your code sample's scope indention, can you please check that out to make it easier for people to help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @PhilippLenssen for the reply.I have watch that video earlier but i don't want to use OnMouseDrag i want to implement through touch to avoid colliders. gonna fix that indentation.

Comment: The input was just one example. The key is to rotate in world coordinates, not local ones, as local ones relative to the object likely won't work as you expect from a static point of view.

Comment: does that mean replacing localAngle = m_objecttorotate.transform.localEulerAngles; line with localAngle = m_objecttorotate.transform.EulerAngles; ?

Comment: or can you please provide improved version of the code?